# Controlling playback of multiple Youtube Videos with the Youtube JS api (playing at the same time)

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I know that there's a very similar topic for this question, however I'm trying to do something a little different.
all of this is a little new for me... sorry...

Basically I'm trying to play multiple YouTube Videos in one page at the same time (mash up style) using YouTube API and JS
the thing is i want to control each of them separately, while they all playing. i found the code that is close to what i want. the thing is that the videos cannot be played together, once you hit play on a video the other one stops.

how can i control them separately, and still have the other videos playing in the background and not being influenced ?

[here's the code i found on another topic](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/dYUB8/)

Thanks in advanced,
 Maayan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [YouTube code playground](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#working_with_multiple_players) has an example for this.