# How to play two Youtube videos simultaneously using iframe API

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-iframe-api

Hi I want to be able to play two (or more) videos simultaneously using Youtube's iframe API.

I've been able to add both videos but one appears playing and the other paused. If I execute playVideo() on the paused one, it starts playing but the one playing gets paused...

Is there a way to override this default behaviour of only one video at a time?

Some bits of the code that creates the video:

```
self.player = new YT.Player(self.playerId, {
    videoId: self.options.videoId,
    playerVars: {
        controls: 0,
        showinfo: 0,
        modestbranding: 1,
        wmode: 'transparent'
    },
    events: {
        'onReady': self.playerReady,
        'onStateChange': self.playerStateChange
    }
});
```

and

```
self.playerReady = function(e) {
    if (self.options.mute) e.target.mute();
    e.target.seekTo(self.options.start);
    e.target.playVideo();
};
self.playerStateChange = function(state) {
    if (state.data === 0 && self.options.repeat) { // video ended and repeat option is set true
        self.player.seekTo(self.options.start); // restart
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to use autoplay feature or play on click ?

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268075/controlling-playback-of-multiple-youtube-videos-with-the-youtube-js-api-playing

Comment: @Skwal that works but it uses SWFOBject, and apparently nothing is done, you can just play multiple videos. However, on the js iframe api videos pause each other, just like if you open many youtube tabs on chrome

Comment: @MartinMassera I am doing something similar. Found out that using the player.playVideo() to be called simultaneuosly in two or more different clients will only play 1 client and the other clients wont play. Were you able to solve this?

Comment: @taimuralam no, I was not

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code, which plays 2 youtube videos simultaneously.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <h1>Two youtube videos Playing Simultaneously</h1>
 </head>
 <body>
  <br>
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/2ggzxInyzVE?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/hHUbLv4ThOo?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
 </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's not iFrame api, but just an iFrame